# Save users data C#

Tags: save

I need to save user temporary data (500 users). I am currently using:

```
DataTable myData = new DataTable();

myData.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
myData.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
...

myData.Rows.Add("1", "name1", ...);
myData.Rows.Add("2", "name2", ...);
...
myData.Rows.Add("500", "name500" ,...);
```

New rows are added/edited, eg 50x per second from one user... and every 1 minute the data are sent to Mysql database.

Is this method sufficiently stable and fast to add/edit/delete a large amount of temporary data?
I was thinking about saving to an xml file, but I think my way is faster ...

Thank you for any advice.

**Edit:**

I have a server and the users (clients) are connected to server, and they send data to server and server send data to them.

E.g. When the client send a message to others clients.

Comment: If this some kind of tracking/logging process and you do not need live data in your database, have you considered logging into a rollover file and process those files to your db later through a background task?

Comment: I have a server and the users (clients) are connected to server, and they send data to server and server send data to them.

E.g. When the client send a message to others clients.

Comment: 50 messages/s multiplied by 500 users is surely rules out producing a hand rolled Xml file. Your task looks more like a use case for [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/uses) (or similar messaging systems).

Comment: And what about the DataTable method? Do you have the experience?